# Using 'when' with deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var self = this;

    var arr = Array();

    $.each(files, function(index, file){

        self.fileRead.read(file).done(function() {

                arr.push(self.fileShow().done();
        })

    });

    $.when.apply($, arr).done(function(){console.log('all done')});
```

self.fileRead returns a deferred, as does, self.fileShow.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

For each files, read the file, when this is done, show the file. When EVERY file has been shown, log 'all done'.

The problem is 'all done' is being logged straight away.

I have also looked at map but with no luck, it seems that methods such as self.fileShow are not even ran.

```
$.when.apply(files, $.map(function(index, file) {
        return self.fileRead.read(file).done(function() {

                return (self.fileShow());
        })

    })).done(function(){console.log('when done')});
```

Code for file read:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {

        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    fileReader.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject(this);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();
```

Code for file show (just a deferred at the minute):

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're printing before anything gets put in arr (you only push a promise into arr after a file is read and shown).

If you're using jQuery < 1.8, you can return your own Deferred object in $.map and resolve it when the file has been read and shown.

```
var self = this;
$.when.apply($, $.map(files, function(index, file) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    self.fileRead.read(file).done(function() {
      self.fileShow().done(dfd.resolve).fail(dfd.reject);
    }).fail(dfd.reject);

    return dfd.promise();
})).done(function() {console.log('when all done')})
   .fail(function() {console.log('when at least one failed')});
```

If you're using jQuery >= 1.8, you can abuse "then", which can be used to chain nested Deferreds (but wastes Deferred objects needlessly):

```
var self = this;
$.when.apply($, $.map(files, function(index, file) {
    return self.fileRead.read(file).then(function() {
      return self.fileShow();
    });
})).done(function() {console.log('when all done')})
   .fail(function() {console.log('when at least one failed')});
```

Comment: I'm using 1.9. The above code (the last block) does not work, it just logs 'when all done' straight away.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in when invocation, can you try the latest?

Comment: Im now getting an error from fileReader, which was working previously. Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

Comment: Never mind, that is because it should be (file, index), your example has it the other way around. Thanks for your help, currently checking the rest of this works.

Comment: Thanks this worked, do you know if there is a way to pass data from a deferred.reject so that it can be operated on in the when.fail?

Comment: yes, fail will receive the parameters defer.reject is run with. So if you do defer.reject(err), the fail function callback will receive err as a parameter. Same with "done". In your case, since "when" operates on multiple deferreds, you'll have multiple arguments in the fail callback.